# Which Doctrine association should I use?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I've two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE server (
     serverId INT
)

CREATE TABLE resource (
     resourceId INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
     serverId INT NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE resource ADD FOREIGN KEY (serverId) REFERENCES server(serverId);
```

In my `server` entity, I'd like to `getResourceList()` which returns a list of resource entities.

What are the correct annotations for this, and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you would like to use Doctrine2 with PHP annotations. Your tables could be rewritten as follows:

*Your **Server** class with annotations:*

```
/**
 * @Id @Column(type="integer")
 * @GeneratedValue
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Resource", mappedBy="server")
 */
private $resources;

public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

public function getResources() {
    return $this->resources;
}

public function addResource(Resource $resource){
    $this->resources->add($resource);
}

public function removeResource(Resource $resource){
    $this->resources->removeElement($resource);
}
```

*Your **Resource** class with annotations:*

```
/**
 * @Id @Column(type="integer")
 * @GeneratedValue
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var Server
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Resource", inversedBy="resources")
 */
private $server;

public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

public function getServer() {
    return $this->server;
}

public function setServer(Server $server) {
    $this->server = $server;
}
```

There is a "one to many" association on the server side since you are mapping MANY resources to ONE server. On the other side of the relationship - logically - there has to be a "many to one" association.

Now after calling the `$server->getResources()` method you would get an ArrayCollection of the associated resource entities.